# Copying data from a datagrid view to a new form with a new datagrid view VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, datagridview

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have created a new VB Windows forms application that uses several forms.

On one of those forms (form2), I create a datagridview based on a number of items that a user picks on form1.

The end user can then add information on the datagridvew and then they go to a third form (form3). On the third form, I would like to copy the same information as the first three columns of the datagrid on form2 into a new datagrid.

To copy the items from the listbox on form1 I use code similar to the following:

```
For Each Feature As Object in form1.listbox1.SelectedItems
Me.DatagridView(Col, Row).Value = DirectCast(CustomerFeature, DataRowView)("Feature").ToString()
Row +=1
Next
```

I want to use:

```
For Each row As DGVRow In form2.DatagridView.Rows
    'add information to the new datagrid
Next
```

on my Form3. However, when I try to access form2 data, it doesn't show up in intellisense, nor will it let me type out the information manually. When I try to run the program I get:

"Error  1   Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."

I can't even access the public variables that I have declared on that form. I should mention that form2 is called using:

```
Private Sub BTN_Next_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTN_Next.Click
        Dim frm_PI_01 As New form2(PIMethod, StartTime, TheUser, TheComputer)
        frm_PI_01.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

and the new method uses:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal PIMethod As String, ByVal StartTime As Date, ByVal TheUser As String, ByVal TheComputer As String)
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    PI_Method = PIMethod
    Start_Time = StartTime
    The_User = TheUser
    The_Computer = TheComputer
End Sub
```

The datagrid is filled in during the onload event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"Error 1 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."`

As this message says: You need a instance of `form2` - object of type `form2`created with `New` sub, which you created inside of `BTN_Next_Click`. But local variable `frm_PI_01` can be used only inside of that function.

With name of class `form2` you can used only `Shared` member or functions/subs [MSDN Shared members in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hbsxy95%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

My opinion if you need transfer some information/variables from form to another then in your case(when you transfer data only once when creating form) use a parameters in form constructors.

Add another parameter to you `form3` constructor. For example reference of your `datagridview`(this is may be not good practice referenced controls to another form, better create some variable with needed data and reference that, but only for example it is easiest way):

```
'Of course create private variable for datagridview
private _dgvForm2 as dataGridView
//Constructor of form3
Public Sub New(dgvForm2 as DataGridView)
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    Me._dgvForm2 = dgvForm2
End Sub
```

After this you can use it in `Load` function...